# How do you create a Adwords BigQuery Transfer and Transfer Runs using the bigquery_datatransfer Python client?

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I have been able to successfully authenticate, and list transfers and transfer runs. But I keep running into the issue of not being able to create a transfer because the transfer config is incorrect.

Here's the Transfer Config I have tried:

```
transferConfig = {
    'data_refresh_window_days': 1,
    'data_source_id': "adwords",
    'destination_dataset_id': "AdwordsMCC",
    'disabled': False,
    'display_name': "TestR",
    'name': "TestR",
    'schedule': "every day 07:00",
    'params': {
        "customer_id": "999999999" -- Changed Number
    }
}

response = client.create_transfer_config(parent, transferConfig)
print(response)
```

And this is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./create_transfer.py", line 84, in <module>
    main()
File "./create_transfer.py", line 61, in main
    response = client.create_transfer_config(parent, transferConfig)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery_datatransfer_v1/gapic/data_transfer_service_client.py", line 438, in create_transfer_config
    authorization_code=authorization_code)
ValueError: Protocol message Struct has no "customer_id" field.
DDIS:bigquery siddharthsudheer$ ./create_transfer.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./create_transfer.py", line 84, in <module>
    main()
File "./create_transfer.py", line 61, in main
    response = client.create_transfer_config(parent, transferConfig)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery_datatransfer_v1/gapic/data_transfer_service_client.py", line 438, in create_transfer_config
    authorization_code=authorization_code)
ValueError: Protocol message Struct has no "customer_id" field.
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to set up a Data Transfer through the API by defining the `params` as class `google.protobuf.struct_pb2.Struct`.

Try if the adding the following works for you:

```
from google.protobuf.struct_pb2 import Struct

params = Struct()
params["customer_id"] = "999999999"
```

And then changing your `transferConfig` to:

```
transferConfig = {
    'data_refresh_window_days': 1,
    'data_source_id': "adwords",
    'destination_dataset_id': "AdwordsMCC",
    'disabled': False,
    'display_name': "TestR",
    'name': "TestR",
    'schedule': "every day 07:00",
    'params': params
    }
}
```

Comment: That helped take the error about struct away but there's the new error: google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 Request contains an invalid argument.

Comment: @ethanenglish I got the same error. Have you resolved it?

Comment: @Rukeith - It's been a while but we decided not to use BQT because it chokes when you have to set up backfills more than 10 days with the load we were sending.